# Append variable to string WITHOUT using $($var) syntax

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to execute the most basic copy-item from a SQL Server Agent task, however it falls over when I use sub-expression statements using the format: `$($var)` due to the `$()` syntax.
More info, kind of, here:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58669/sql-agent-powershell-step-syntax-error

I don't know PowerShell at all but I have this from Googling:

```
$Datetime = get-date -format "yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss"
Copy-Item -Path "F:\Grange\PROD\Gwineupd.csv" -Destination "F:\Grange\PROD\Archive\Gwineupd $($Datetime).csv"
```

I need to replace $($Datetime) with something that doesn't use that format...
Is it possible?

Comment: `"F:\Grange\PROD\Archive\Gwineupd "+$Datetime+".csv"` should work too.

Answer (score 1):

Try pre-building the file name, like so:

```
$Datetime = get-date -format "yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss"
$destination = "F:\Grange\PROD\Archive\Gwineupd{0}.csv" -f $Datetime
Copy-Item -Path "F:\Grange\PROD\Gwineupd.csv" -Destination $destination
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the `$()` syntax:

```
Copy-Item -Path "F:\Grange\PROD\Gwineupd.csv" -Destination "F:\Grange\PROD\Archive\Gwineupd $Datetime.csv"
```

In Powershell, variables in double quoted strings are substituted automatically.

Comment: Worth mentioning the [about_quoting_rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) documentation, as this covers `"` vs `'` quotes and evaluated expressions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always qualify the variable name with `{}`, no need to use `$()` inside a string:

```
"F:\Grange\PROD\Archive\Gwineupd ${Datetime}.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another alternative,
directly piping the source and building the destination name from source parts with the `-Format` operator.

```
Get-Item "F:\Grange\PROD\Gwineupd.csv" |
  Copy-Item -Destination {"{0}\Archive\{1}_{2:yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss}{3}" -f `
    $_.Directory, $_.BaseName, (Get-Date), $_.Extension}
```